# What to consider when signing up for VG Wort?

Tags: publications, germany

I am a German citizen and have published my PhD thesis this year and am thus thinking of signing a contract (“Wahrnehmungsvertrag”) with VG Wort. Essentially, it seems like taking free money for my thesis and articles (which I would write in any case) without any downsides. In this question, I would like to clarify whether there are really no downsides.

1. I am fine with VG Wort to duplicate my works wherever (as long this does not infringe any rights of the copyright holders, see below) and most of the legalese seems to consists of various ways for duplication I allow VG Wort.
2. I have published articles at various subscription-based journals (from Springer, Elsevier, IOP, …) and signed the corresponding copyright agreements. These do not stop me from getting paid for these articles by VG Wort, correct?
3. I am surely not allowed to sign a similar contract with another corporation – but I guess there will probably be no other opportunities in any case?
4. Do I have to ask my coauthors for approval before sending an article to VG Wort?
5. Does VG Wort gain the rights to utilize *any* of my (academic) publications? Or just those which I manually add in their tool?

   1. Am I in some sense obligated to tell them about publications?
   2. If so, does this also hold for, say, lecture notes I put on my website?
6. Is there any other potential problem?

**Main question:** Apart from some initial bureaucratic effort, are there any downsides for me signing such a contract with VG Wort?

Comment: Don't plan on actually getting any 'free money' from you thesis...

Comment: For any non-Germans, what is VG WORT?

Comment: @Jeroen: The VG stands for “Verwertungsgesellschaft“ with Wikipedia translates as “Copyright collective” (but this probably mixes up different legal terms). In case you heard of GEMA: It's like that for texts. In very simple (and surely slightly wrong terms): Say your copyrighted book is used in a school, borrowed in a library or in part copied somewhere, then you can get money for that and VG WORT gets the money for you.

Comment: @Keba, no legal advice from my side. But I have seen quite a few PhD candidates collecting the money from VG Wort, and as far as I can tell they were all happy. You do not expect to commercialise your dissertation text in any other way, do you?

Comment: @Snijderfrey: Of course I was not expecting any legal advice here. And yes, I do not plan to commercialize my works in any other way.

Comment: Is there anything about this question that would change if your writing was not academic writing?  E.g. a work of popular fiction?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: While the laws and contracts the same, many aspects of them are either only relevant to academic writing or not relevant at all, in particular given the peculiarities of the academic publishing system as well as generally low reader numbers. Thus the academic’s perspective is quite different from the novelist’s one, for example. Also, VG Wort has a distinct reporting system for academic publications.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is helpful to realise that the VG Wort is all about monetizing secondary use (“Zweitverwertung”) of creative works, i.e., [lawfully permitted uses of works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limitations_and_exceptions_to_copyright), e.g., copying for teaching.
This is opposed to primary use such as a journal selling a copy of an issue to a library or a single paper to a reader.

Secondary use is almost inherently impossible to directly monetise because it would be too tedious for everybody involved and enable copyright holders to effectively block lawfully permitted uses.
Instead there are special fees on devices used for secondary use such as printers or computers that the VG Wort collects and then distributes to both, authors and publishers.

The legal documents regarding this are rather convoluted, in particular VG Wort’s contract could have been made easier to read for humans.
Since this is not legal advice anyway, I will not excessively cite them but leave it to you to check them in accordance to the level of certainty you desire.
A brief overview of the most important parts:

- § 60h UrhG ([English](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0465), [German](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/__60h.html)) entitles authors to remuneration for secondary uses, which must be “asserted through a collecting society”.
- In the [VG Wort’s contract (“Wahrnehmungsvertrag”)](https://www.vgwort.de/fileadmin/pdf/wahrnehmungsvertrag/Wahrnehmungsvertrag_Muster_Dez_2021.pdf), § 1 covers the various secondary uses of copyrighted material covered by VG Wort (many of which are practically irrelevant to scientific publication). § 2 restricts all of this to works of text and asserts that certain rights of the author are not touched.

With all of that being said, let’s move to your individual points:

> I am fine with VG Wort to duplicate my works wherever […] and most of the legalese seems to consists of various ways for duplication I allow VG Wort.

VG Wort is not interested in copying your work.
Other people have a right to copy your work under certain conditions (lawfully permitted use) and you are entitled to remuneration for this.
You entrust these rights and managing the remunerations to VG Wort.
(There are also aspects like rental, which are a bit more complicated.)

> I have published articles at various subscription-based journals (from Springer, Elsevier, IOP, …) and signed the corresponding copyright agreements. These do not stop me from getting paid for these articles by VG Wort, correct?

Correct.
From a pragmatical point of view, VG Wort knows how scientific publishers work and scientific publisher know VG Wort (and also receive remuneration via it).

> I am surely not allowed to sign a similar contract with another corporation – but I guess there will probably be no other opportunities in any case?

Correct. VG Wort is a society per bestowal by the state (“Verein kraft Verleihung”).
German copyright law mandates that you can only collect remunerations for secondary use via such a collection society (§ 60h UrhG, see above), and VG Wort is the only one covering scientific texts.

> Do I have to ask my coauthors for approval before sending an article to VG Wort?

No.
In general you need such approval when you are acting on somebody’s behalf – which should be made very clear to you, e.g., when transferring copyright to a journal (though some journals contact each author for this individually).

> Does VG Wort gain the rights to utilize any of my (academic) publications? Or just those which I manually add in their tool?
>
> Am I in some sense obligated to tell them about publications?

You transfer the rights for all your publications.
Reporting publications is only something VG Wort requires you to do if you want to receive any money.

> If so, does this also hold for, say, lecture notes I put on my website?

Technically, yes.
Texts published in the Internet can be remunerated by VG Wort.
You need to provide proof of how often they have been accessed (via a counting pixel) and you need to reach a minimum of 1500 visits.
I find it unlikely that lecture notes or similar will reach this or it is worth the effort.

> Apart from some initial bureaucratic effort, are there any downsides for me signing such a contract with VG Wort?

I am not aware of any downsides. It’s mostly about collecting money that you are entitled to anyway.

> free money for my thesis

At a first glance, to receive remuneration for your thesis, it has to be “properly” published (with ISBN and stuff) – which is unlikely.
Also due to the low number of copies, it’s probably not worth the effort to register it.

Comment: Also, increasingly, libraries cancel subscriptions to print journals. Most of my publications that I have reported to VG Wort in recent years have not been accepted for monetization because of that. It used to be a nice way to get up to 100 € per year but I'm not sure if it's worth bothering anymore.